# ngFor not showing data from firebase realtime database - Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ngfor

***CaptorService***

```
export class CaptorsService {
  private dbPath = "/auto/captor";
  captorsRef: AngularFireList<any> = null;
  constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.captorsRef = database.list(this.dbPath);
  }

  getAll(): AngularFireList<any> {
    return this.captorsRef;
  }
}
```

***CaptorComponent***

```
export class CaptorsComponent implements OnInit {
  captors: any[];

  constructor(private captorsService: CaptorsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.retrieveCaptors();
  }

  public retrieveCaptors(): void {
    this.captorsService
      .getAll()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map((changes) => changes.map((c) => ({ key: c.payload.key }))))
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.captors = data;
      });
  }
}
```

***Template***

```
<div *ngFor="let captor of captors">{{captor.key}}</div>
```

***When the data is loaded from Firebase, It displayed on the console, but nothing showing in the DOM.***

Comment: Try making those methods asynchronous

Comment: @AhmedSHA256 If you could just give a hint about it ?

Comment: Because i think the problem is from ngFor, because When i just prompt the data, you can see it as an array of Object, but when i try to iterate through it, nothing happened

Comment: can you do console.log(this.captors) just to see what you are getting

Comment: Yes, I just read your whole question. I will try to answer you.

Comment: @PeterHaddad, when i write console.log inside the subscribe, it take some time and show the whole Array, but when I write it outside i find it undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating n divs, each one for every item retrieved. I don't know if this is a bad practice, but as long as I know, you shouldn't do that.
What you should do is, inside of that **div**, create a **list**, like this:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let captor of captors">
      {{captor.key}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is how I usually do that kind of thing, and if you are populating properly your **captor** array, this should work.

Also, if you want to double check if your captor array is well populated, try to create a button that shows in the console that array, like this:

HTML:

```
<button (click)="showData()">CLICK ME!</button>
```

COMPONENT:

```
showData() {
  console.log(this.captors)
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using divs as opposed to lists. All depends on what and how you want to display it.

Comment: No, i just do that for tests right now

Comment: Well, as I can read in your comments, your problem is that you are trying to render the data when the component is created. This is fine when you have your data instantly, but in this case you are retrieving it from firebase, which it takes some time), so you will have to wait until the data is retrieved, and then render something. You can do this with an ng-template and conditions, or with asyncrhonous methods as I mentioned earlier.